# Is there a term for referencing the main character in a first-person song?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

Is there a specific word for the protagonist when the singer sings from the protagonist's point of view?

For example, in the song ["Two Is Better Than One"](http://www.lyricsmania.com/two_is_better_than_one_lyrics_boys_like_girls.html) by Boys Like Girls:

> I remember what you wore on the first day
>   You came into my life and I thought
>   "Hey, you know, this could be something"

Comment: the... _singer_?

Comment: Please can you give an example of lyrics that do this. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @MattЭллен- I went through a few thought revisions, discarding several possibilities before I decided that OP must be asking how to refer to the original first person subject of the song.  Not necessarily the current singer and not "I or me" within the song lyrics themselves, but for example in the song, "I'm singin' in the rain", is there something better than *the guy* that we could use to discuss the protagonist.

Comment: @Matt: Like Johnny Cash's _A Boy Named Sue_. What would you call Sue in that song? (besides Sue, I mean.)  Or maybe the "me" in Janis Joplin's _Me and Bobby McGee_.

Comment: @Matt Эллен: Jim is correct. If you need more context, specifically the song is _Two Is Better Than One by Boys Like Girls_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use the term persona.

Comment: You should give some detail as to why this fits.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I don't see a problem with *protagonist*. From NOAD:

> **protagonist** (*n*.) the leading character or one of the major characters in a drama, movie, novel, or other fictional text.

Answer (score -1):

*Hero*, *challenger* — just like that.

Comment: Please give an example of how this would fit into lyrics sung from a first person perspective.